# Ajax Cross Domain Call not going to success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

Hi I have developed a Web application Using Spring mvc. In that I have a method which returns the JSON data. When I call that method it will return the JSON data.

But When i call the same method from a separate HTML page using AJAX it is not going to success function.

Spring Method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ManageDepartmentsMOb",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<?> manageDepartmentsMob(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
 {
   List<DepartmentManagement> deptList = departmentManagementService.findAll();  
   return deptList;
 }
```

My External HTML Page's ajax call

```
$.ajax({
      type : "GET"
      url : "http://localhost:8080/sta/ManageDepartmentsMOb",
      dataType : "JSONP",
      success : function(data)
      {
              alert("Success");
      }

});
```

As I directly call my spring method it returns the JSON data as you can see in screen shot.

[image]

Comment: What does network panel in Chrome Dev tools show?

Comment: Json response is not getting and In chrome network panel response tab is not showing

Comment: Try to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to your response. Start by the value `*` just to see if it works: `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`.

Comment: @sp00m  Where i need to add this line?

Comment: @MohammedFarooq In your `manageDepartmentsMob` method.

Comment: @sp00m I tried with tat. Still same no changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your Web.config.

```
 <system.webServer>      
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origins" value="*" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>
```

Also try to return a Json from your method like

```
return Json(deptList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```